# Two updates with one condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to do 2 updates together in one statements and I was hoping using the updates within a transaction clause will help this. But it did not. 
So below, I was expecting it to find the record and update it. but it does the first one and when it goes to the second that the value "Expired" is 0 already.
How can I do this? (docid ='Syn25331' is just to test with one record. But I want to do it for thousands of record, hence without the docid ='Syn25331' condition)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

Update main
Set expired = 0
where Expires > GETDATE() and Expired =1 and docid ='Syn25331'


Update main
Set TractorID = AssetID
where Expires > GETDATE() and Expired =1 and docid ='Syn25331'

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need a comma here to update both columns:

```
Update main
Set expired = 0, TractorID = AssetID
where Expires > GETDATE() and Expired = 1
```

Comment: Added that to the post

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in a single update statement

```
UPDATE main
SET    expired = 0,
       TractorID = AssetID
WHERE  Expires > GETDATE() AND
       Expired = 1
```